# What does Wireshark do to my Windows settings that improves the Wifi performance?

Tags: wireshark

I'm here because we have very slow Wifi performance with brand new Dell laptops (XPS 13 9360).  For troubleshooting purposes I have downloaded and installed Wireshark (64bits, with Winpcap).

I did not even have to capture and analyze any data to improve the performance!  Just launching Wireshark without any changes to the options yields 80Mbps speeds vs 200kpbs!

I only have this issue in our offices.  Anywhere else the Wifi speed is fine.

Can someone offer any insight what changes Wireshark makes to the Windows (10) networking configuration?  If I close it, the speed remains extremely fast, until a reboot.  Might our Cisco Access point require these changes to offer decent performance?  Of is there any option or firmware update that might be required to not have to open Wireshark?

Thanks!

Eric

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that wireshark is enabling promiscuous mode. I can’t think why it would increase the speed you’re seeing unless there is an issue somewhere. Try turning promiscuous mode on in the device manager NIC settings and see if you get the same result.

Comment: Related: https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/50123/win-2012-r2-vm-network-much-faster-after-wireshark-was-started

Comment: I'd be willing to bet it isn't doing anything.  Just coincidence. How do you know Wireshark is improving the speed?

Comment: Well without Wireshark opened I was getting around 200kps on average.  With it opened I would get around 60-80Mbps.    It turned out that the solution in the end was to set the MTU down from 1500 to 1400 and now we are getting steady througput at around 100-120 Mbps!